# Should I nest screens within the navigator function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm currently developing an App in which multiple screens use the same data. Rather than declaring multiple loose functions and passing the same props everytime, I've nested them all in the same function that returns the navigator, which contains all data I need to use between the screens.

```
   ...imports...

   const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

   const HomeNav = ({route, navigation }) =\> {

    ... states, variables, and functions
    
    
    
    const Scr1 = ({ navigation }) => {
            ... stuff with states and data above
        );
    }
    
    const Scr2 = ({ navigation }) => {
            ... other stuff 
        );
    }
    
    
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{drawerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#000000'}, drawerActiveTintColor:'#ffffff', drawerInactiveTintColor:'#DADADA'}} 
        initialRouteName="Casa" 
        drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
            ... drawers
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    )
```

that's a cut down version of my code, to explain better. My screens, Scr1 and Scr2, are in the same function as the navigator.

Things work most of the time. I can easily share data between screens, but I'm having a LOT of problems with undefined objects and useless rerenders. I created a hook with the data that's getting loaded as the state, so whenever it efectively loads, the screen gets rerendered. But I have multiple data variables, so the hook gets called as each one finishes loading. And if I remove those hooks, I lose my defined objects.
Anyway, **bottom line**, my question is if what I'm doing could give me problems in the future, if it's the 'right' way to do things as to not complicate further down the road. If so, I find a way to deal with the rerenders, otherwise I change my code while I'm still beggining.

[Full Homenav.js on github](https://github.com/mlmartin2/PalaApp/blob/refat/PalaFront/components/homenav.js)

That's the complete file, if it helps
pretty messy, but I'm learning react so I'm just going at it
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's anti-pattern to define/declare React components within other React components. They should be declared external to any other component. The issue is that because they are redeclared each render they are remounted instead of just being rerendered.

Comment: Thanks , I'll rework the code then. Good day